# Affine transformation as a composition of three linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be an affine trasformation defined as $$Tx:=Ax+b,$$ where $A$ is a matrix $(a_{ij})$, $i,j=1,\dots, n$ and $x,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let us suppose that $\det A\ne 0$. This transformation can be written as a composition of three linear transformations, $T_1, T_2, T_3$, where $$T_1x:=\frac{A}{|\det A|}x,\quad T_2x:=|\det A|x,\quad T_3x=x+b.$$

Let us consider the following collection of subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$: $$(a_1,b_1]\times (a_2, b_2]\quad (a_i, b_i\in\mathbb{R}; a_i\le b_i, i=1,2)$$
$$(-\infty, b_1]\times (a_2,b_2], \quad (a_1,b_i]\times (-\infty, b_2]$$
$$(a_1, b_1]\times (a_2,\infty), \quad (a_1,\infty)\times (a_2,b_2]$$

> It is clear to me how $T_2$ and $T_3$ work. How does $T_1$ work instead?

Comment: $T_3$ is not linear, it is affine.

Comment: What do you mean with "how $T_1$ work"? $T_1$ is a linear application that sends a vector $\vec{x}\to \frac{A}{|\det A|}\vec{x} $ that is another vector

Comment: @TurquoiseTiltI mean how it acts on those sets, that is, how they are transformed.

Comment: I think a little bit but in order to understand how $T_1$ works I think we need more information. What $T_1$ does is strictly linked to the matrix $A$ ( could be a rotation, deformation, projection ecc...), at least this is my opinion. I've tried computing explicitly since in $\mathbb{R}^2$ isn't that hard (if you want I can show you)  but at least for me nothing special happens. In life never knows, I'll be happy to be contradicted if is the case :)